# Assign value to variable after cut?

Tags: linux

As a Unix newbee, I wish to parse the file's full path

`/Users/E/atsp_0001.tar.gz`

into `0001` and assign the `0001` to variable `sub_id`.

The parsing, although maybe clumsy, works like this:

```
E$ file=/Users/E/atsp_0001.tar.gz
E$ echo ${file##*/} | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1
0001
```

Then, I failed to assign the `0001` to a variable like this:

```
E$ file=/Users/E/atsp_0001.tar.gz
E$ sub_id=${file##*/} | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1
E$ echo ${sub_id}

E$
```

I would greatly appreciate it, if anyone could
(1) explain why this is not working and how to fix it, and (2) improve the clumsy parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we do it. You can use `$()`. You can also use `` instead of `$()`but I would not recommend it.

```
:~> file=/Users/E/atsp_0001.tar.gz
:~> echo ${file##*/} | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1
0001
:~> variabletest=$(echo ${file##*/} | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1)
:~> echo $variabletest
0001
```

You are doing multiple operations in variable assignment rather than storing the value which is why it is not working for you

`echo` will print the data but you were doing piped operation so that wont work until you enclose it to mark it as a one single operation. Your parsing is OK since it depends on your file naming conventions. But I would use base name command

```
:~> echo $file
/Users/E/atsp_0001.tar.gz

:~> basename $file
atsp_0001.tar.gz
```

This will strip the path out.

So you can do `variabletest=$(echo basename $file | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! (1) So the `echo` does not mean `print`, does it? (2) Isn't the parsing clumsy?